# SQL - Difference between SPACE(2) + '|' + SPACE(2) and ‘ | ‘?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any difference between using `SPACE(2) + '|' + SPACE(2)` or just `' | '`? I know the output will be the same but I'm not sure about other aspects... Actually I can't see the point in using SPACE function if there's no difference...

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first difference which comes to my mind is the amount of spaces. Let's say you'd like to write 20 spaces, a word and another 20 spaces:

```
'                    abcd                    '
```

How many spaces are there? Much more useful:

```
SPACE(20)+'abcd'+SPACE(20)
```

Isn't it?

There are many cases in which you edit somebody's code generating SQL queries. It's more than probable that you delete a space somewhere and not possible to debug it. There's no such problem if `SPACE` function is used.

Comment: Not to mention, you can add spaces up to the maximum length of a normal varchar in T-SQL (8000)

Comment: To include spaces in Unicode data, or to return more than 8000 character spaces, use REPLICATE instead of SPACE.

Answer (score 16):

I agree with others who have answered this that SPACE() is useful to indicate the number of spaces used or to add large numbers of spaces.

Using SPACE may also be simpler if you want to generate a fixed-width format file - you can use the data length as a parameter e.g.

```
SELECT 
  name + SPACE(20-LEN(name))
FROM
  SomeTableWithNames
```

Answer (score 5):

Its more clear to see SPACE(50) compared to

50 spaces..

```
  "                                               "
```

Thats my reason.

Comment: I See others posted the same as i said just about the same time.  e

Answer (score 4):

No, there's no difference.

The point of the `SPACE` function comes when there are more spaces (say 20), or you wish to make the number of spaces clear to the reader.